# SQLite Multithread Mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, sqlite

I am using SQLite in my C++ application.  SQLite threading mode is set to multi-thread so that multiple threads which share single database connection would be allowed.  In this scenario do I need to wrap database operation as shown below?  Or is this not required?

```
void SomeClass::someDbOperationOnAThread(void *arg) {
    sqlite3_mutex_enter(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
    // Perform some queries on the database
    sqlite3_mutex_leave(sqlite3_db_mutex(db));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) says:

> 2. **Multi-thread**. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads.

So you cannot use a single connection for multiple threads.

In any case, a single connection can have only a single transaction, so it would be a better idea to have a separate connection for each thread.

Comment: Thanks @CL. .  So, say multiple threads have their own connections to the database, then, should the operation still have mutexes?

Comment: What mutex? And what would the mutex protect?

Comment: Mutex as you see in the code snippet in my question.  What would be protected is SomeClass's member property, let's say, a value returned from INSERT(last row ID, for example).

Comment: With `sqlite3_db_mutex()`, each thread would have its own mutex, so this would be pointless. (Anyway, in multi-thread mode, [sqlite3_db_mutex()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_mutex.html) returns NULL.)

Comment: Can multiple threads support writing to database at the same time?

Comment: The same docs also says `Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction.` and `The default mode is serialized.`. Your answer is incorrect. You can use single connection over multiple threads. There is no reason for creating a connection per thread.

Comment: Also multiple connections don't support parallel transactions. All writes to SQLite database are serialized anyway.

Comment: @freakish The question is not about serialized but multi-thread mode.